# Poltergeist throws error when running visit command in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, poltergeist

I'm trying to replace the capybara-webkit driver with poltergeist for my specs that need javascript. I'm getting this weird error though and I can't find anyone else having the same issue. It's when running the visit command that the following error occurs:

```
Failure/Error: visit edit_path(:model_name => "field_test", :id => @record.id)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `parser' for Faye::WebSocket:Class
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/poltergeist-1.0.2/lib/capybara/poltergeist/web_socket_server.rb:20:in `initialize'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/poltergeist-1.0.2/lib/capybara/poltergeist/web_socket_server.rb:99:in `new'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/poltergeist-1.0.2/lib/capybara/poltergeist/web_socket_server.rb:99:in `accept'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/poltergeist-1.0.2/lib/capybara/poltergeist/web_socket_server.rb:143:in `send'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/poltergeist-1.0.2/lib/capybara/poltergeist/server.rb:29:in `send'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/poltergeist-1.0.2/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:168:in `command'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/poltergeist-1.0.2/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:21:in `visit'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/poltergeist-1.0.2/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:81:in `visit'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/capybara-1.1.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:157:in `visit'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/capybara-1.1.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:161:in `visit'
     # ./spec/integration/config/edit/rails_admin_config_edit_spec.rb:698:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `instance_eval'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `block in run'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:254:in `with_around_each_hooks'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:111:in `run'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:390:in `block in run_examples'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `map'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `run_examples'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:371:in `run'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `block in run'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `map'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:372:in `run'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
     # /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Answer (score 2):

There was a problem with gem dependencies, the bundler installed faye-websocket v0.5 but poltergeist was not compatible with that version. Fixed by adding faye-websocket 0.4.4 dependency to my app.

Comment: This helped me, thanks. Not able to run the latest version of poltergeist since im using REE.